# Bird identification by sound; midwestern US

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

This one's been bugging me for a couple of years. Location is southwest Michigan.

Here are a couple of song samples (I couldn't separate it from the Titmouse... they're pretty chatty these days):

- [Unidentified Bird 1](https://www.serialhobbyists.org/files/UnidentifiedBird1.flac)
- [Unidentified Bird 2](https://www.serialhobbyists.org/files/UnidentifiedBird2.flac)

Closest I can come up with is an Eastern Towhee, but the trill doesn't seem quite right. All the samples I've been able to find have it pretty constant in pitch and tempo, but this one gets a little higher and slower as it goes on.

This is a rural area. Our property is about half grass/prairie, half wooded. The sounds seem to come from a line of tall evergreens at the front of our property (an otherwise more open area), but I have yet to actually find the bird, so I can't be sure. A creek runs behind our house in a wooded area, about 400 feet from where the sounds appear to be emanating. These clips were taken about an hour after sunrise.

Can anyone identify this bird?

Comment: Can't really help, but if you aren't already aware of it, [xeno-canto](https://www.xeno-canto.org/) provides a good database of bird calls.

Comment: Xeno-Canto (fm ning's comment) seems to be a good site with well-versed users, and has a ["mysteries" page where you can submit](https://www.xeno-canto.org/mysteries).